# How do I get coloured text on my view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a `ViewData["Error"]` for a view of mine which I call like this:

```
<p><strong><%: ViewData["Error"] %></strong></p>
```

and I want to let the text appear as red on the view.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the [css tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/default.asp) from w3schools.

Comment: w3schools just terrible. it became better over the last 1 or 2 years, but is still full of wrong and outdated information. please don't recommend such a bad site. for more information, please take a look at http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="color:red"><strong><%: ViewData["Error"] %></strong></p>
```

Easiest, but probably not the best. You might want to add a class with semantic meaning and provide a style for that class.